# Java GUI object becomes null after passing it to a class

Tags: java, swing, oop, object, netbeans

I am trying to pass an object of type Warehouse between two of my GUI classes and for some reason it becomes null after passing it. Is it being garbage collected? If so how do i stop it?

This is the first class which instantiates the warehouse object and fills it with dummy data and opens a new Jframe on a button prompt which i am trying to send the data to.

```
public class StaffLeaveMainMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Warehouse staffList = new Warehouse();
/**
 * Creates new form StaffLeaveMainMenu
 */
public StaffLeaveMainMenu() {
    staffList.createTestData();
    System.out.print(staffList);
    initComponents();
}

private void jButtonManagerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    ManagerMenu newFrame = new ManagerMenu();
    newFrame.setWarehouse(staffList);
    newFrame.setVisible(true);
}  
}
```

Then this is the class it is being sent to:

```
public class ManagerMenu extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private Warehouse staffList;
/**
 * Creates new form ManagerMenu
 */
public ManagerMenu() {
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    System.out.print(staffList);
    refreshListModel();
    initComponents();
}

public void setWarehouse(Warehouse objTarget) {
    staffList = objTarget;
}
}
```

Comment: If it's becoming `null`, there is some code doing this. Show us the full code or at least an example that reproduces the error. And no, it's not being garbage collected.

Comment: How exactly do you see `staffList` is `null`?

Comment: as long as you have a reference to access your object at all, it will not be garbage collected.

Comment: I put in comments from inside the first class and it returns: staffdatamodel.Warehouse@341dce73                                                                Then in the second class it returns as null

Comment: @SamBooty This means that it is **not** null. Otherwise it would return `null`.

Comment: Yes it return as not null in the first class, then when i try to use it in the second class the System.out.print(staffList); returns null.

Comment: Show me where are you trying to `println` it.

Comment: @Gabriel Edited origional post

Comment: yes, you print it in the constructor of ManagerMenue, without initializing it, so it is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`staffList` is null inside `ManagerMenu`'s constructor because you are passing it *after* calling the constructor.

To solve it, you have to pass it in the constructor itself, not in a setter.

```
public ManagerMenu(Warehouse objTarget) {
    staffList = objTarget;
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    System.out.print(staffList);
    refreshListModel();
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much, don't know why i didn't see that :0